Strange behavior of numpy meshgrid
The Python code
import numpy as np

def mesh(l):
    g = np.array(np.meshgrid(*l))
    return np.moveaxis(g, 0, -1)

mesh([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

gives the output
array([[[[1, 3, 5],
         [1, 3, 6]],

        [[2, 3, 5],
         [2, 3, 6]]],


       [[[1, 4, 5],
         [1, 4, 6]],

        [[2, 4, 5],
         [2, 4, 6]]]])

Why is the third and then the first index changing? I expected it to look like

[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
etc.


did you pay attention to the indexing parameter?
